# Java - how to create delays

Tags: java, swing

I'm wondering how can I make a Java program delay parts of code to prevent spamming buttons/other things in the program. So let's just say I'm making a program that displays the amount of times a user has clicked a button. I would like there to be a delay to the user cannot click the button rapidly. I heard that java timers could help me, but I can't find any tutorial explaining what I need done.

```
public void ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    count+=1;
    labelA.setText(Integer.toString(count));
}
```

This is just an example program, not what im actually working on. So can someone please help me? I need to have a program create a delay so the user cannot spam buttons. Thanks :) (this is a revised question from before)

Comment: Did the [official Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) link not help?

Comment: @Reimeus timer is overkill for this particular problem. timeMillis() is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save an instance variable in your action listener called `long lastClicked` and initialize it to 0.

in your handler:

```
int delay = 1000;
if(System.currentTimeMillis() > lastClicked + delay)
{
    //do your click
    lastClicked = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

A delay of 1000 would be 1 second.

Comment: Thank you soo much, im been looking for such a long time for this :) Works perfectly thanks you :)!!!

Answer (score 4):

If you have a field `timer` of  [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html),

```
private Timer timer;
```

you can create the instance in the constructor or a init method:

```
final ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        button.setEnabled(true);
    }
};
timer = new Timer(2000, listener);
timer.setRepeats(false);
```

In this case, the delay is `2000` miliseconds before enabling the button again.

You can start it in the click event of the button.

```
button.setEnabled(false);
timer.start();
```